# Angular 2+ Передача объекта в дочерний компонент

Tags: angular2, typescript

В родительском компоненте есть массив:

```
items: string[];// в нём хранятся id
```

При событии элемента 'mouseover' в массив добавляются элементы:

```
on('mouseover', _ => items.push(id));
```

При событии элемента 'mouseout' из массива удаляются элементы:

```
on('mouseover', _ => items = items.filter(item => item != id));
```

Если после этих строчек я помещаю строку `console.log(items)`, в консоли отображается всё как надо - элемент добавился, элемент удалился

Массив через шаблон передаётся в дочерний компонент:

```
[items]="items"
```

В дочернем компонете создал `set` с директивой `@Input()` чтобы поставить там `console.log(items);`:

```
//это дочерний компонент
_items: string[];
@Input()
set items(items: string[]) {
  console.log(items);
}
```

Этот код срабатывает только когда происходит событие `'mouseout'`. Консоль показывает пустой массив `items`: `[]`. Получается, что будто бы в дочерний элемент поступает только пустой массив. 
И вроде всё как по учебнику, но не работает.

**Жду ваших мыслей по поводу того, что я делаю неправильно**

Comment: > `Жду ваших мыслей по поводу того, что я делаю неправильно` -> Жду твоего _воспроизводимого примера_ на codesandbox :) Подожди, а почему у тебя биндинг называется `hoveredItems`, а ты в шаблоне провайдишь `[items]`?

Comment: @overthesanity, вроде понятно всё и без codesandbox, а замечание исправил

Comment: понятно тебе, как автору вопроса. Мне непонятно, потому что есть куча нюансов который могут на это влиять. [См. Справка > Как задавать вопросы > Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). А задавать последовательно кучу вопросов я не вижу смысла, слишком большая демагогия выйдет. Воспроизводимый пример решает все эти проблемы. Если ты не видишь смысла создавать примеры, то я не вижу смысла помогать тебе. Возможно, кто-то другой поможет. Удачки :)

Comment: @overthesanity, дружище, спасибо тебе за всё, но я уже решил проблему :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается, если в `'mouseover'` ивенте написать:

```
items = items;
```

по сути это же костыль, поэтому я использовал BehaviorSubject([]), передал его в дочерний компонент и в методе `ngOnInit()` подписался на него и использовал все его изменения как божью милость

[Вот здесь рассказывается про BehaviorSubject и про другие Subject'ы](https://medium.com/@kosmogradsky/subject-%D0%B2-rxjs-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-c9099231be6d)

Надеюсь, это кому-нибудь поможет